# How to limit the form submission per day on kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

so here I am making a booking service application where later there will be a maximum user limit for inputting booking data. what I'm asking is how to provide quota limits to users for input per day. thnx

> The limit here means to give the user a data input quota, so if the input quota is used up, the user cannot input data into the database again

below is the source code for inputting data to the database
`

```
val Modeldatabase = ModelDatabase(platnomor, tahunkendaraan, serieskendaraan, nama, alamat, nomorhp, tanggalservice, keluhane)
database.collection("Data Booking").document(nama).set(Modeldatabase)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        pltnomor.text?.clear()
        thnkendaraan.text?.clear()
        srskendaraan.text?.clear()
        namapmlk.text?.clear()
        alamatpmlk.text?.clear()
        nohpe.text?.clear()
        tglbooking.text?.clear()
        keluhankerusakan.text?.clear()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Booking Sukses!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }.addOnFailureListener{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Booking Gagal!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

`

i hope to find a solution how to make max limit for input data

Comment: What do you mean limits?

Comment: The limit here means to give the user a data input quota, so if the input quota is used up, the user cannot input data into the database again

Comment: You are not input data to database, you are saving data to database.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: the code doesn't actually have a problem but I want to add a feature where there is a user limit for inputting data every day. for example today the user can only input 3 data @AlexMamo

Comment: What do y ou mean by "today the user can only input 3 data"? Would you like the user to perform only three addition operations?